# Python wriring data from Excel File

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, pyautogui

I'm attempting to loop through lines of an excel file and write the data in a web application.  I'm using a mixture of openpyxl to get the excel data and pyautogui to click and type in the web application.  However, when I get to the point to enter the data:

```
c=Sheet.cell(row=i,column=7).value
    pyautogui.typewrite(c)
```

I get an error "for c in message: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".  Is there any way I can get around this?  It sounds like pyautogui can only type exact strings, not read from variables?

```
import openpyxl
import pyautogui
import time
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('H:\\Python Transfer.xlsx')
type (wb)
wb.get_sheet_names()
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
lastRow = Sheet.max_row
for i in range(2,lastRow + 1):
    #print(Sheet.cell(row=i,column=7).value)
    pyautogui.click(1356,134)
    time.sleep(5)
    c=Sheet.cell(row=i,column=7).value
    pyautogui.typewrite(c)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(1528,135)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I assume pyaugogui sends keystrokes one character (or key) at a time, so maybe try converting c to a string; pyautogui.typewrite(str(c))

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typewrite()` takes a string, so convert c to a string:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(str(c))
```

See the docs:
http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html